# Execute jar command exclude files

Tags: java, jar

I followed [The Java Archive Tool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jar.html) but couldn't find how to exclude folders.

For example, I have the files under working copy directory:

```
workingcopy
--src
  --.svn
  -- com
--.svn
--WebContent
```

I would like to compile and create jar only from the classes under `src` excluding all folders starting with .svn directory. I want to run it from `cmd` like `jar -cf test.jar` etc..

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a practical workaround for your problem: it will not *exclude* the subversion directory (directories) but include only class files (assuming, you *don't* put class files under version control):

```
jar -cf test.jar *.class
```

Further enhancement: separate code from class files. You don't want to check in class files (build artefacts) anyway:

```
workingcopy
--src
  --.svn
  -- com  // only *.java files in here and below
--.svn
--WebContent
--bin
  --com   // only *.class files in here and below
```

Comment: I have only the Java classes there. Can I also compile it to classes via jar or any other command line not with ANT?

Comment: @Odelya - use `javac` to compile java source files and (optionaly) `jar` to create libraries. `jar` can't compile and you don't *need* ant or maven, but especially ant greatly simplifies the build process (but you have to learn/understand ant basics). maven simplifies even more but maven is somewhat harder to understand. And it requires (permanent) internet connection.

Comment: @Anderas_D yes I worked with Maven but didn't like it since the plugin for eclipse caused alot of extra work and not everything was compiled. until I find a good plugin I don't want to go back to Maven and pom.xml. I know how to use ANT but it was simple for me to execute it from FinalBuilder without and external file for build.xml

Answer (score 24):

This can be done with a command:

```
jar cf test.jar `find . -not -path "*/.svn/*" -not -type d`
```

The problem with `jar` is that if directory is passed it will be added recursively with **all** content. So our goal is to pass only files and only those of them which doesn't have '.svn' substring in the path. For this purpose `find`  command is used with 2 conditions:

1. `-not -path "*/.svn*"` filters out all svn files
2. `-not -type d` filters out all directories

This will exclude empty directories from the jar though.

Comment: This has decreased my build time substantially. Thank you.

Comment: how elegant :)! great unix solution for the cripple jar tool :). This is great for older versions, at least in Java 11 one can use : jar cvf MyWarFile.war !(folder1) or jar cvf MyWarFile.war !(file1|folder1) for multiple exclusions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept called Export in SVN. if you use that you will get the structure without the .svn repository. It is slightly different from the Check-Out.

After this you must be able to do a regular jar command from that directory instead of the repository folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved (along with many other things) by build tools like [maven](http://maven.apache.org) and [ant](http://ant.apache.org) and [gradle](http://gradle.org/)

Answer (score 0):

As said by [javamonkey79](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591552/execute-jar-command-exclude-files/4591650#4591650), I don' tthink you can do this just with the `jar` tool itself. What you should do is considering [ant](http://ant.apache.org/), and its [jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html).

Answer (score 0):

From Java 11 you can use exlamation mark (!) to exclude files or folders, seperated by pipe (|)
Examples:

```
jar cvf MyJarFile.jar !(file1)


jar cvf MyJarFile.jar !(file1|folder1)
```

On Java 8 jar, see the great answer using find from @silnijlos

You can also use maven, ant or gradle if you have that available, reference for maven:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like the jar program *by itself* will be able to do this. You will need to add in some other type of script to accomplish what you are looking for.

It looks like you may be using windows, so my guess is that you could write in this missing pieces that way.

Hope this helps.