# Compiling .jar Recursively With Wildcards

Tags: java, maven, android-studio, jar

I'm trying to compile an Android Studio Project manually (yes, I know Maven is better). Running 
`jar -cf Package.jar *` compiles both the `.java` files and the `.class` files into the `jar`, when I only want the `.class` files in there. Any way to do this?

I've tried `*.class`, which leads to an error.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591552/execute-jar-command-exclude-files

Comment: That's the question I have, but running `*.class` yields an error, as does the accepted answer. Maybe it's because I'm developing on Windows and using `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 0):

on Unix, you can use the find command to generate a list of files for the jar and include them like so:

```
find . -name '*class' -print0 | xargs -0 jar cvf foo.jar
```

Or from your existing jar, you can [delete the unwanted files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4520932/783412) using zip:

```
find . -name '*java' -print0 | xargs -0 zip -d myjar.jar
```